# run vs cmd - shouldn't it be the same?

Tags: command-line

I have a console *.exe file.

the wierd thing is that if I run the file by double clicking it - the output is one thing.
but if I run the file through the cmd window - the output turns out different.

I checked it several times, and it's consistent.

why would this happen?..

thanks.

Comment: Different working directory perhaps? Some more info would be nice...

Comment: I down-voted this terrible question. No good information on what is happening or how the app was developed. to boot, it's coming from a user who just can't be bothered to click a Vote or Accept now and again as thanks for all the answers he's gotten.

Comment: Member for 33 days, no questions accepted, no votes cast.

Comment: What Paul and Andrew said.

Comment: @Paul Tomblin: and he's gotten numerous decent answers, to boot, including discussion back to his follow-ups. How hard is it to take one second to learn how to click a link here or there to say, "thanks!"

Comment: Seems like this guy is the poster boy for these people: http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/

Comment: Wow! Take it eazy guys! I'm new to this site. I didn't not vote in purpose! I'm not a vampire, thkala and there is no point in being obnoxious.. I'll vote up!

Comment: Well, I tried voting up, but it says I don't have enough reputation for that.. what do I do?

Comment: This question is marginal for a couple of reasons: (1) you haven't told us what platform you are working on (I'm guessing windows, but you should *say* so) (2) how is this a programming question and not a user question?  To vote up acquire 15 or more rep (you'll need 100 to vote down); accepting answers is worth 2 rep per, so if you have received answer you have used, jump in. Writing good questions that get voted up will get you 5 each, good answer net 10 per vote.

Answer (score 4):

Can't say much without the actual output in both cases, but my guess would be that it is one of the following:

1. The environment variables are different.
2. The program is able to detect how it is started.
3. The icon you clicked on the desktop actually has some property settings attached.

Answer (score 0):

ooa program *is* a command, every command *is* a program

have you ever noticed that when you don't input a normal command it reads
something like "'what you typed' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

notice the operable program part
also have you ever thought that those cmd commands (i.e. cd, dir, ftp) are on your hard drive

because they are

when you type "dir" in a cmd window it actually loads the program called dir

the computer thinks that your program is one of the systems

so it simply loads in the same window

the way you load it does not effect the program it just effects how it is shown

if you don't like clicking: run: "your program.exe" than just make a shortcut on your desktop

tell me if anything is poorly explained

Comment: Rubbish. you could be a Indian meditation guru meditating over computer concepts with paradoxes, in a part of india where nobody knows about computers. You haven't figured out the technicalities.